# How to validate windows user?

Tags: directoryentry

I use the following code to validate the users who belong to our company domain. This works fine.

```
using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry(""))
{
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

    ds.Filter = "(|(&(objectCategory=user)(name=domainuser)))";
    ds.PropertyNamesOnly = true;
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
    ds.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.None;

    SearchResultCollection src = ds.FindAll();

    bool isValid = false;
    try
    {
        foreach (SearchResult sr in src)
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
            de.Password = "domainpassword";
            object nativeObject = de.NativeObject;


            if (nativeObject != null)
                isValid = true;

            break;
        }
    }
    catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException ex) {}

    return isValid;
}
```

The actual problem is that I need to create an LDAP instance in my laptop (MYINSTANCE) and then I need to create users programmatically. I'm able to create users and iterate through them.

Now for such users I'm not able to validate the user name and password.

The change I made was as below.

```
using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://MYPC:389/CN=MYINSTANCE,DC=COMPANYDOMAIN,DC=com", "domainuser", "domainpassword", AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
{
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

    ds.Filter = "(|(&(objectCategory=user)(name=instanceuser)))";
    ds.PropertyNamesOnly = true;
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
    ds.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.None;

    SearchResultCollection src = ds.FindAll();

    bool isValid = false;
    try
    {
        foreach (SearchResult sr in src)
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
            de.Password = "instancepassword";
            object nativeObject = de.NativeObject;


            if (nativeObject != null)
                isValid = true;

            break;
        }
    }
    catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException ex) {}

    return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work on .NET 3.5 or higher, you can use the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace and easily verify your credentials:

```
// create a "principal context" - e.g. your domain (could be machine, too)
using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MYINSTANCE", 
                                "CN=MYINSTANCE,DC=COMPANYDOMAIN,DC=com", 
                                ContextType.SecureSocketLayer,
                                "domainuser", "domainpassword")
{
    // validate the credentials
    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("myuser", "mypassword");
}
```

It's simple, it's reliable, it's 100% C# managed code on your end - what more can you ask for? :-)

Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Comment: When I use this code, I get the following error. "The server could not be contacted." When I use using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "COMPANYDOMAIN", "CN=MYINSTANCE,DC=COMPANYDOMAIN,DC=com", ContextOptions.SimpleBind, "domainuser", "domainpassword") now i don't have this error, but it always returns false.

Comment: @BerylWilson: you say you're *creating an LDAP instance* on your laptop - does that mean you're using AD LDS (Active Directory - Lightweight Directory Services) ?? I believe that AD LDS cannot be used for authentication....

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. You are right. I followed this link. http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2010/07/12/getting-started-with-active-directory-lightweight-directory-services.aspx. I'm struggling with this problem for quiet some time. Is it possible to refer some official pointers (MSDN) if AD LDS cannot be used for authentication? Me too googling on the same.

Comment: @BerylWilson: if you specify "SecuteSocketLayer" as your ContextType - then yes, that requires SSL

Comment: :With SimpleBind is it possible to authenticate? refering to your earlier statement "I believe that AD LDS cannot be used for authentication..."